# Contract gives me a ParserError: Expected primary expression

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License_identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0;

import "./struct.sol";

contract storageFactory{

  function createSimpleStorageContract()  public{
    struct simpleStorage = new struct();
  }
}
```

the code for struct.sol is:

```
// SPDX-License-identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0;

contract storageb{
  struct people{
    uint256 favN;
    string name;
  }

  people[] public array;
  mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavNumber;

  function addPerson( string memory _name,uint _favN) public{
    array.push(people(_favN, _name));
    nameToFavNumber[_name]=_favN;
  }

}
```

Compiler error:

```
from solidity:
    ParserError: Expected primary expression.
    --> learn/storagrFactory.sol:9:9:
      |
    9 |         struct simpleStorage = new struct();
      |         ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please can you specify what do you do in your code? Do you want to instantiate a struct?

Answer (score 1):

The contract name in `struct.sol` is `storageb` and not `struct` (which is a solidity keyword).

Calling `import "struct.sol";` is quite similar to copy&paste content of `struct.sol` in your `storagrFactory.sol`

You need to use `storageb` instead of `struct` in `storagrFactory.sol` to make your contract compile.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your function to this:

```
function createSimpleStorageContract()  public {
    storageb simpleStorage = new storageb();
  }
```

Hope it helps!